# Jquery with toggle , add "required" attribut into input field when div visible and remove it when its hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

i'm new with jquery and i have a problem with my codes, i would make the checkbox as a toggle with jquery, and when the checkbox "clicked" and the toggle shows the div, then add required attribut into the checkbox input, and when it "clicked" again and the toggle is hidden then remove the required attribut. But when in the third "click" the toggle is show up but not adding required attribut into the checkbox input,

And I want the code to continue to run like that logic.

```
Here is my codes
HTML

  <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">
                            <div class="form-outline flex-fill mb-0">
                              <label for="checkbox1" class="switch" id="les">
                                <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="user">
                                <div class="slider round"></div>
                              </label>
                             
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          <div id="exmImg" style="display: none">
                            <label for="expImg" class="form-label">Contoh Gambar</label><br>
                            <img src="/imgs/mb.jfif" alt=""  class="img-thumbnail mb-3"><br>
                            <label for="gmb" class="lblGmb form-label" id="szz">
                              Upload file
                            </label>
                            <input type="file" class="gambarEx form-control d-none" name="exmImg" id="gmb">
                          </div>

SCRIPT
  <script>
                            
                            $(document).ready(function(){
                              $("#checkbox1").click(function(){
                                $("#exmImg").toggle("fast");
                                $("#gmb").attr("required", true);

                                $("#checkbox1").click(function(){
                                      $("#gmb").removeAttr("required");
                                    });
                              });
                            });
                      
          
  </script>
```

Thanks you guys...

Comment: If your question contains code, please format it so that other users can read it

Comment: Thanks for the advice, this is my first question with stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Toggling the `required` property of the `#gmb` element should do the trick.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#checkbox1").click(function () {
        $("#exmImg").toggle("fast");
        let gmb = $("#gmb").get(0);
        gmb.required = !gmb.required;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this code works very well now I have many options for similar cases

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){                   
       $("#checkbox1").change(function(e){              $ 
          ("#exmImg").toggle("fast");            
          if(e.target.checked) {             
            $("#exmImg").css("display","block");               
            $("#gmb").attr("required", true);
          } else{                                  
            $("#exmImg").css("display","none");  
            $("#gmb").removeAttr("required");
          }
       });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot the code works very well, I'll learn into this trick.